# Do I have to declare an iPhone 6 when entering China?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china

I'm wondering if I have to declare my personal, used iPhone 6 when entering China as a tourist. Will they make me pay tax on it because it is an expensive phone?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17969/3067).

Comment: @alx9r – no it is not, this is country specific. China has very particular customs laws. Thank you.

Comment: Sure.  Every country has specific laws.  That's why that other question has a different answer for each country/customs area.

Comment: Except it doesn't cover China...

Comment: Yep.  The question is a duplicate, the answer not.

Answer (score 5):

According to [travelchinaguide.com](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/essential/customs.htm) that is not necessary:

> Question: I’m traveling to China with my Iphone, Ipad, and MacBook. Do I need to
>   declare them and pay the tax when I enter China?
>
> Answer: You do not need to declare and pay the tax for your personal
>   items, such as smart phone, tablet PC, laptop, and digital camera, if
>   within reasonable quantity (one for each). However, if you are taking
>   another brand new phone or laptop with the outer packing and
>   instruction book as a gift for your friend in China, you should
>   declare the new one and pay the tax.

Answer (score 2):

According to my personal experience you don't have to declare it as long as it's not new item. I entered  China with my IPhone, Samsung tablet, and Dell Laptop. No problem.